# Getting the keys corresponding to the values (in tuple format) containing the largest number

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as follows: the keys are integers from 1 to 109, and the values are either `False` or `True`. If `True`, the value will be a tuple containing a number, such as `(True, 0.9)`. The sample dictionary looks like this:

```
myDictionary = {1: False, 
                2: (True, 0.9),
                3: False,
                4: (True, 0.3),
                5: (True, 0.11), 
                ...
                ...
                107: (True, 0.9),
                108: False,
                109: (True, 0.84)}
```

I would like to get the keys corresponding to the values that contain the largest number in the tuple. In the snippet above, it would be `2` and `107`. If more than 1 pair contain the largest value, I would like to have them both. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Take a look a using `items()` on your dictionary and a list you will use to append items to that are equal to your current maximum.  If you find a new maximum, reset the list to empty and append the new maximum.  Once you have run through all the items, you should have a list containing the ones that are equal to the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max` with a custom `key` function get the max value, then just filter the dict for the relevant keys:

```
d = {
    1: False,
    2: (True, 0.9),
    3: False,
    4: (True, 0.3),
    5: (True, 0.11),
    107: (True, 0.9),
    108: False,
    109: (True, 0.84),
}

max_value = max(d.values(), key=lambda x: x or (False, 0))
max_keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if v == max_value]

## max_keys: [2, 107]
```

Comment: I would suggest `max_value = max(d.values(), key=lambda x: x or (False, 0))`.

Comment: Beautiful, I will edit the answer accordingly :)

Comment: The original question doesn't allude to any performance issues. However, it's worth pointing out that this approach takes 3 times as long as the proposed single pass approach

Comment: @Fred While that's true, the asymptotic complexity is still `O(n)` in both cases. So unless performance is absolutely critical I'd prefer a simple and readable solution over a complicated one any day.

Answer (score 1):

Start by finding the maximum value:

```
>>> [v[1] for k, v in myDictionary.items() if isinstance(v, tuple)]
[0.9, 0.3, 0.11, 0.9, 0.84]
>>> max_val = max(v[1] for k, v in myDictionary.items() if isinstance(v, tuple))
```

and then find the keys corresponding to that value:

```
>>> [k for k, v in myDictionary.items() if isinstance(v, tuple) and v[1] == max_val]
[2, 107]
```

Comment: I'd change `isinstance(v, tuple)` to `v`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a single pass over the dictionary's items:

```
myDictionary = {1: False, 
                2: (True, 0.9),
                3: False,
                4: (True, 0.3),
                5: (True, 0.11), 
                107: (True, 0.9),
                108: False,
                109: (True, 0.84)}

m = float('-inf')
keys = None

for k, v in myDictionary.items():
    if v:
        _, n = v
        if n > m:
            m = n
            keys = [k]
        elif n == m:
            keys.append(k)

print(keys)
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 107]
```